# Sequel : DRY between schema migration and model validate method

Tags: ruby, validation, sequel

I'm wondering if I miss a way to avoid repeat validation code in my Sequel::Model#validate subclass method since I've already put all constraints into my migration file.

Here's a simple example of what I'm talking about :

```
  Sequel.migration do
    change do
      create_table :users do
        primary_key :id
        String  :name, :null => false, :unique => true
      end
    end
  end

  class User < Sequel::Model
    def validate
      super
      validates_presence :name
      validates_unique :name
      validates_type String :name
    end
  end
```

It seems very painful and errors prone to have to repeat all the constraints in the validate method. Did I miss something or there's no other way to do that ?

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why do you need validations in migration? When you create a new table, it will be empty, nothing to validate. When you drop it, who cares about data validity? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequel has some nice [plugins and extensions](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/plugins.html).

```
Sequel::Model.plugin(:auto_validations)
Sequel::Model.plugin(:constraint_validations)
```

and

```
DB.extension(:constraint_validations)
```

### auto_validations

> The auto_validations plugin automatically sets up three types of
>   validations for your model columns:
>
> - type validations for all columns
> - not_null validations on NOT NULL columns (optionally, presence
>     validations)
> - unique validations on columns or sets of columns with unique indexes

See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/AutoValidations.html

### constraint_validations

> The constraint_validations extension is designed to easily create
>   database constraints inside create_table and alter_table blocks. It
>   also adds relevant metadata about the constraints to a separate table,
>   which the constraint_validations model plugin uses to setup automatic
>   validations.

See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/constraint_validations_rb.html
and 
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/ConstraintValidations.html

### Your example would look like this

```
Sequel::Model.plugin(:auto_validations)
Sequel::Model.plugin(:constraint_validations)

Sequel.migration do
  up do
    extension(:constraint_validations)

    create_table :users do
      primary_key :id
      String :name, :null => false, :unique => true

      validate do
        presence :name,
                 name: :presence_name
      end
    end
  end

  down do
    extension(:constraint_validations)

    drop_table(:users)
  end
end

class User < Sequel::Model
end
```

Comment: That was exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't think it should be in the plugins.
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's normal. Don't worry.

Comment: Well, that's the point. To respect the DRY we shouldn't have to do this. All the constraints should trigger implicitly the related validation checks without having to write them down explicitly in the validate method. Thus in the Model instance we should only have to focus on specific validation/constraints not already handled by the database.